# APIKey Authentification missing for /transit/Departures v8

Tags: here-api

I am having trouble using the "Next Departures" call as described here:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/public-transit/api-reference-swagger.html

I clearly states that an authentification via APIKey should be possible, however I always get an 
"Bearer token invalid. Bearer missing or bearer value missing."

All other calls to the api work fine with my APIKey methode, also if I generate a Bearer Token and use this, it works. However generating a Token that expires for just this call, is not my preferred method.

As the documentation also includes the APIKey method, I guess this is a bug, or I am doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter “&apikey”  (all small letters) and it will work.